# Usages of the word "hacky"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the word "hacky" means and what is the differences between the words "hack" and "hacky"

For example: "I found a hacky solution"

Is this means the solution is awful or means cheating but solves anyway?

Comment: The word *hack* is a noun. While *hack* could have been used as a noun adjunct in this sentence, the word *hacky* here is the corresponding adjective. I don't usually see it, so I'm surprised it appears in [dictionaries.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hacky)

Comment: It appears in *Webster's Unabridged*. However, most in America would immediately think of the trade name Hacky Sack--a small, sock-like ball that can be kicked about either alone or in a small group.

Comment: "Hack" is a well known term (both verb and noun) in US computer programming and engineering circles.  It means a solution which is inelegant and ugly but gets the job done (at least temporarily).  "Hacky", in this sense is simply an adjective for the verb/noun.The terms "hacking" and "hacker" have a fairly long and somewhat separate history and do not (or did not traditionally) mean what the modern press would have you believe.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "hack" is very often preceded by "quick" -- [quick hack](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quick+hack&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquick%20hack%3B%2Cc0).  This since 1985, so obviously it's a computer term.  The pair does appear prior to that, but more in the sense of hacking with an axe or hitting with a karate kick.

Answer (score 3):

It's not all as bad as you say - hacking does not necessarily mean cheating, and I wouldn't go so far as saying hacky means awful. Usually a hack means you at least finished your task.

That being said, neither is *good*, really. The [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hacky) definition linked in the comment doesn't get it totally right. [These definitions go a little further](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/H/hack.html) (you can skip the bit about MIT).

Another friend told me, "Programmers are sometimes proud of a hack (in the way that you're impressed by something MacGyver does with only chewing gum and nail clippers), but it has the connotation of being a temporary solution that is going to cost you in the long run. To summarize: the negative connotation is accurate."

Answer (score 0):

Among stand-up comedians I've heard "hack" used as an adjective, as in "That bit was hack". But it is more commonly used as a noun. As an adjective, it is used interchangeably with "hacky" to mean "cliche" or "uninspired."

This *may* be what it means in your quote (although you should give a bit more context).

Answer (score 0):

As a technical writer with one foot in the technical world and the other in the literary one, I don't think "hacky" is inherently negative *or* positive. It simply means a solution that involved an unconventional or unanticipated modification.